# How do I print a second card in my Cards class?

Tags: java, object, javafx

this is where the cards are being printed:

```
package cc4;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import reusable_classes.Card;

public class maybeCHeck extends Application {

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) throws FileNotFoundException {         
        //Drawing a cardOutline 
        Rectangle cardOutline = new Rectangle(); 

        //Creates horizontal box "image1" that contains the image and add the image
        cardOutline.setX(380); 
        cardOutline.setY(480); 

        //Setting the properties of the cardOutline 
        cardOutline.setWidth(300.0); 
        cardOutline.setHeight(480.0); 

        //Setting the height and width of the arc 
        cardOutline.setArcWidth(30.0); 
        cardOutline.setArcHeight(30.0);  
        cardOutline.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        cardOutline.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        //Creating a Group object  
        Group root = new Group(cardOutline); 

        //Creating a scene object 
        double xScene = 600.00;
        double yScene = 600.00;

        //if it is a value card like 2 - 10, make the rank a N and if it a rank card like a J, Q, K, make the value card into anything that isnt 2 - 10
        Card Card=new Card (10, "Diamond", 'N' );


        if (Card.getSuit()=="Club") {

            //top left of the card (suit)
            HBox suitTopLeft = Club(stage);
            suitTopLeft.setTranslateX(25);
            suitTopLeft.setTranslateY(100); 

            //bottom left of the card( the suit)
            HBox suitBottomRight = Club(stage);
            suitBottomRight.setRotate(180);
            suitBottomRight.setTranslateX(260);
            suitBottomRight.setTranslateY(405);

            //middle of the card( the suit)
            HBox suitMiddle = Club(stage);
            suitMiddle.setTranslateX(125);
            suitMiddle.setTranslateY(210);
            suitMiddle.setScaleX(0.5);
            suitMiddle.setScaleY(0.5);


            root.getChildren().add(suitTopLeft);
            root.getChildren().add(suitBottomRight);
            root.getChildren().add(suitMiddle);
        }
        else if (Card.getSuit()=="Spade") {

            //top left of the card (suit)
            HBox suitTopLeft = Spade(stage);
            suitTopLeft.setTranslateX(25-26);
            suitTopLeft.setTranslateY(100+40); 
            suitTopLeft.setRotate(180);

            //bottom left of the card( the suit)
            HBox suitBottomRight = Spade(stage);
            suitBottomRight.setTranslateX(260-40);
            suitBottomRight.setTranslateY(405-40);

            //middle of the card( the suit)
            HBox suitMiddle = Spade(stage);
            suitMiddle.setTranslateX(125-19);
            suitMiddle.setTranslateY(210+100);
            suitMiddle.setScaleX(0.5);
            suitMiddle.setScaleY(0.5);
            suitMiddle.setRotate(180);

            root.getChildren().add(suitTopLeft);
            root.getChildren().add(suitBottomRight);
            root.getChildren().add(suitMiddle);
        }
        else if (Card.getSuit()=="Heart") {

            //top left of the card (suit)
            HBox suitTopLeft = Heart(stage);
            suitTopLeft.setTranslateX(25-15);
            suitTopLeft.setTranslateY(100-15);
            suitTopLeft.setScaleX(0.25);
            suitTopLeft.setScaleY(0.25);

            //bottom left of the card( the suit)
            HBox suitBottomRight = Heart(stage);
            suitBottomRight.setRotate(180);
            suitBottomRight.setTranslateX(260-28);
            suitBottomRight.setTranslateY(405+5);
            suitBottomRight.setScaleX(0.25);
            suitBottomRight.setScaleY(0.25);

            //middle of the card( the suit)
            HBox suitMiddle = Heart(stage);
            suitMiddle.setTranslateX(125-5);
            suitMiddle.setTranslateY(210-15);
            suitMiddle.setScaleX(0.5);
            suitMiddle.setScaleY(0.5);


            root.getChildren().add(suitTopLeft);
            root.getChildren().add(suitBottomRight);
            root.getChildren().add(suitMiddle);
        }
        else if (Card.getSuit()=="Diamond") {

            //top left of the card (suit)
            HBox suitTopLeft = Diamond(stage);
            suitTopLeft.setTranslateX(25+70);
            suitTopLeft.setTranslateY(100-5); 

            //bottom left of the card( the suit)
            HBox suitBottomRight = Diamond(stage);
            suitBottomRight.setRotate(180);
            suitBottomRight.setTranslateX(260-27);
            suitBottomRight.setTranslateY(405);

            //middle of the card( the suit)
            HBox suitMiddle = Diamond(stage);
            suitMiddle.setTranslateX(125+120);
            suitMiddle.setTranslateY(190);
            suitMiddle.setScaleX(0.5);
            suitMiddle.setScaleY(0.5);


            root.getChildren().add(suitTopLeft);
            root.getChildren().add(suitBottomRight);
            root.getChildren().add(suitMiddle);
        }

        //prints out the text of the card if the value is between 2 - 10
        
        if (2<=Card.getValue()&&Card.getValue()<10) {
            if(Card.getSuit()=="Spade"||Card.getSuit()=="Club") {
                Text text = new Text(178,120, String.valueOf(Card.getValue()));
                text.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));

                Text text1 = new Text(398,520, String.valueOf(Card.getValue()));
                text1.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));

                text1.setRotate(180);

                root.getChildren().add(text);
                root.getChildren().add(text1);
            }
            
            else {
                Text text = new Text(178,120, String.valueOf(Card.getValue()));
                text.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));

                Text text1 = new Text(398,520, String.valueOf(Card.getValue()));
                text1.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));
                text1.setRotate(180);
                text.setFill(Color.RED);
                text1.setFill(Color.RED);

                root.getChildren().add(text);
                root.getChildren().add(text1);
            }
        }
        else if (Card.getValue() ==10) {
            Text text = new Text(170,120, String.valueOf(Card.getValue()));
            text.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));

            Text text1 = new Text(386,520, String.valueOf(Card.getValue()));
            text1.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));

            text1.setRotate(180);
            text.setFill(Color.RED);
            text1.setFill(Color.RED);

            root.getChildren().add(text);
            root.getChildren().add(text1);
        }

        else if(Card.getRank() != 'N') {
            if(Card.getSuit()=="Spade"||Card.getSuit()=="Club") {

                Text text = new Text(178,120, String.valueOf(Card.getRank()));
                text.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));

                Text text1 = new Text(398,520, String.valueOf(Card.getRank()));
                text1.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));
                text1.setRotate(180);

                root.getChildren().add(text);
                root.getChildren().add(text1);
            }


            else {
                Text text = new Text(178,120, String.valueOf(Card.getRank()));
                text.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));

                Text text1 = new Text(398,520, String.valueOf(Card.getRank()));
                text1.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));
                text1.setRotate(180);
                text.setFill(Color.RED);
                text1.setFill(Color.RED);
                root.getChildren().add(text);
                root.getChildren().add(text1);
                
            }
        }
        


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, xScene, yScene, Color.GREEN);  

        cardOutline.setX(xScene/2-150);
        cardOutline.setY(yScene/2-240);

        //Setting title to the Stage 
        stage.setTitle("cardOutline");

        //Adding scene to the stage 
        stage.setScene(scene); 

        //Displaying the contents of the stage 
        stage.show(); 
    } 

    public HBox Club(Stage stage) {

        Circle suitClubs1 = new Circle();
        suitClubs1.setTranslateX(100.0f);
        suitClubs1.setTranslateY(100.0f);
        suitClubs1.setRadius(50.0f);

        Circle suitClubs2 = new Circle();
        suitClubs2.setTranslateX(95.0f);
        suitClubs2.setTranslateY(100.0f);
        suitClubs2.setRadius(50.0f);

        Circle suitClubs3 = new Circle();
        suitClubs3.setTranslateX(-50.0f);
        suitClubs3.setTranslateY(30.0f);
        suitClubs3.setRadius(50.0f);

        Rectangle stem = new Rectangle(); 
        stem.setTranslateX(-112.0f);
        stem.setTranslateY(120.0f);
        stem.setWidth(20.0); 
        stem.setHeight(100.0);

        HBox root = new HBox(suitClubs1, suitClubs2, suitClubs3, stem);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setScaleX(0.25);
        root.setScaleY(0.25);

        HBox clubsRoot = new HBox(suitClubs1, suitClubs2, suitClubs3, stem);
        clubsRoot.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        clubsRoot.setScaleX(0.25);
        clubsRoot.setScaleY(0.25);
        clubsRoot.setTranslateX(-30);
        clubsRoot.setTranslateY(120);           
        return clubsRoot;

    }

    public HBox Spade(Stage stage) {
        Circle suitSpade1 = new Circle();
        suitSpade1.setTranslateX(100.0f);
        suitSpade1.setTranslateY(100.0f);
        suitSpade1.setRadius(50.0f);
        suitSpade1.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        Circle suitSpade2 = new Circle();
        suitSpade2.setTranslateX(80.0f);
        suitSpade2.setTranslateY(100.0f);
        suitSpade2.setRadius(50.0f);
        suitSpade2.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        Polygon suitSpade3 = new Polygon();
        suitSpade3.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                62.0, 170.0,
                230.0, 170.0,
                146.0, 260.0,
        });
        suitSpade3.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        suitSpade3.setTranslateX(-94.0f);
        suitSpade3.setTranslateY(170.3f);    

        Rectangle stem = new Rectangle(); 
        stem.setTranslateX(-187.0f);
        stem.setTranslateY(70.0f);
        stem.setWidth(20.0); 
        stem.setHeight(100.0);

        HBox clubsRoot = new HBox(suitSpade1, suitSpade2, suitSpade3, stem);
        clubsRoot.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        clubsRoot.setScaleX(0.25);
        clubsRoot.setScaleY(0.25);
        clubsRoot.setTranslateX(-30);
        clubsRoot.setTranslateY(120);           
        return clubsRoot;
    }

    public HBox Heart(Stage stage) {
        //drawing the suit with clubs
        Circle suitHeart1 = new Circle();
        suitHeart1.setTranslateX(100.0f);
        suitHeart1.setTranslateY(100.0f);
        suitHeart1.setRadius(50.0f);
        suitHeart1.setFill(Color.RED);

        Circle suitHeart2 = new Circle();
        suitHeart2.setTranslateX(80.0f);
        suitHeart2.setTranslateY(100.0f);
        suitHeart2.setRadius(50.0f);
        suitHeart2.setFill(Color.RED);

        Polygon suitHeart3 = new Polygon();
        suitHeart3.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                62.0, 170.0,
                230.0, 170.0,
                146.0, 260.0,
        });
        suitHeart3.setFill(Color.RED);
        suitHeart3.setTranslateX(-94.0f);
        suitHeart3.setTranslateY(175.3f);       

        HBox root = new HBox(suitHeart1, suitHeart2, suitHeart3);
        return root;
    }

    public HBox Diamond(Stage stage) {
        Polygon suitDiamond1 = new Polygon();
        suitDiamond1.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                90.0, 170.0,
                230.0, 170.0,
                160.0, 280.0,
        });


        suitDiamond1.setFill(Color.RED);
        suitDiamond1.setTranslateX(-94.0f);
        suitDiamond1.setTranslateY(179.0f);     
        Polygon suitDiamond2 = new Polygon();
        suitDiamond2.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                90.0, 170.0,
                230.0, 170.0,
                160.0, 60.0,
        });
        suitDiamond2.setFill(Color.RED);
        suitDiamond2.setTranslateX(-234.0f);
        suitDiamond2.setTranslateY(70.0f); 

        HBox root = new HBox(suitDiamond1, suitDiamond2);
        root.setScaleX(0.25);
        root.setScaleY(0.25);

        return root;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        launch(args); 
    } 
}
```

this is the Card class:

```
package reusable_classes;

import javafx.scene.Group;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import reusable_classes.Card;

public class Card {
    private int value;
    private String suit;
    private char rank;
    private Group imageFront;
    private Group imageBack;

    public Card()
    {}
    public Card(int value, String suit, char rank) {
        this.setSuit(suit);
        this.setValue(value);
        this.setRank(rank);
    
    }
    public void setSuit(String suit) {
        this.suit = suit;   
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setRank(char rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        return this.suit;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public char getRank() {
        return this.rank;
    }
```

I want to print a second card and add it to the root. How would I do this?
Ex: since Card Card=new Card (10, "Diamond", 'N' );
Card Card1 =new Card (2, "Spade", 'N' );

I tried to create a duplicate one but since Card1 isnt mentioned in any of the objects, it isnt called meaning nothing happens and it ignores card1.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: You are going to have to redo your card layout**.

Issues:

- Use `String#equals("..."`) to compare `Strings`.
- Things like `Card Card` should be `Card card`.
- Create a static builder or build the card view in the class `Card` that will return the view.

Here is your code refactored. I took your code and created a `Static` builder. You can also build in the constructor and set `imageFront`. From there, you can have a method like `#getImageFront();` I hope this helps you move forward. Good luck!

---

**Main**

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) throws FileNotFoundException {    
        //Creating a scene object 
        double xScene = 600.00;
        double yScene = 600.00;

        //if it is a value card like 2 - 10, make the rank a N and if it a rank card like a J, Q, K, make the value card into anything that isnt 2 - 10
        Card card1 = new Card (10, "Diamond", 'N' );
        Group card1View = Card.buildCardFront(card1);

        Card card2 = new Card (5, "Club", 'N' );
        Group card2View = Card.buildCardFront(card2);
       
        
        HBox root = new HBox(card1View, card2View);
        
        //Way to create lots of cards!
//        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
//        {
//            Card card = new Card(i + 1, "Spade", 'N');
//            Group cardView = Card.buildCardFront(card);
//            root.getChildren().add(cardView);
//        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, xScene, yScene, Color.GREEN);  
        //Setting title to the Stage 
        stage.setTitle("cardOutline");
        //Adding scene to the stage 
        stage.setScene(scene); 
        //Displaying the contents of the stage 
        stage.show(); 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        launch(args); 
    } 
}
```

---

**Card**

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public final class Card {
    private int value;
    private String suit;
    private char rank;
    private Group imageFront;
    private Group imageBack;

    public Card()
    {}
    public Card(int value, String suit, char rank) {
        this.setSuit(suit);
        this.setValue(value);
        this.setRank(rank);
    
    }
    public void setSuit(String suit) {
        this.suit = suit;   
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setRank(char rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        return this.suit;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public char getRank() {
        return this.rank;
    }
    
    public static Group buildCardFront(Card card)
    {
        Group root = new Group();
        
         //Drawing a cardOutline 
        Rectangle cardOutline = new Rectangle(); 

        //Creates horizontal box "image1" that contains the image and add the image
        cardOutline.setX(380); 
        cardOutline.setY(480); 

        //Setting the properties of the cardOutline 
        cardOutline.setWidth(300.0); 
        cardOutline.setHeight(480.0); 

        //Setting the height and width of the arc 
        cardOutline.setArcWidth(30.0); 
        cardOutline.setArcHeight(30.0);  
        cardOutline.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        cardOutline.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        root.getChildren().add(cardOutline);
        
        
        switch (card.getSuit()) {
            case "Club":
                {
                    //top left of the card (suit)
                    HBox suitTopLeft = Club(root);
//                    suitTopLeft.setTranslateX(25);
//                    suitTopLeft.setTranslateY(100);
                    //bottom left of the card( the suit)
                    HBox suitBottomRight = Club(root);
                    suitBottomRight.setRotate(180);
                    suitBottomRight.setTranslateX(260);
                    suitBottomRight.setTranslateY(405);
                    //middle of the card( the suit)
                    HBox suitMiddle = Club(root);
                    suitMiddle.setTranslateX(125);
                    suitMiddle.setTranslateY(210);
                    suitMiddle.setScaleX(0.5);
                    suitMiddle.setScaleY(0.5);
                    root.getChildren().add(suitTopLeft);
                    root.getChildren().add(suitBottomRight);
                    root.getChildren().add(suitMiddle);
                    break;
                }
            case "Spade":
                {
                    //top left of the card (suit)
                    HBox suitTopLeft = Spade(root);
                    suitTopLeft.setTranslateX(25-26);
                    suitTopLeft.setTranslateY(100+40);
                    suitTopLeft.setRotate(180);
                    //bottom left of the card( the suit)
                    HBox suitBottomRight = Spade(root);
                    suitBottomRight.setTranslateX(260-40);
                    suitBottomRight.setTranslateY(405-40);
                    //middle of the card( the suit)
                    HBox suitMiddle = Spade(root);
                    suitMiddle.setTranslateX(125-19);
                    suitMiddle.setTranslateY(210+100);
                    suitMiddle.setScaleX(0.5);
                    suitMiddle.setScaleY(0.5);
                    suitMiddle.setRotate(180);
                    root.getChildren().add(suitTopLeft);
                    root.getChildren().add(suitBottomRight);
                    root.getChildren().add(suitMiddle);
                    break;
                }
            case "Heart":
                {
                    //top left of the card (suit)
                    HBox suitTopLeft = Heart(root);
                    suitTopLeft.setTranslateX(25-15);
                    suitTopLeft.setTranslateY(100-15);
                    suitTopLeft.setScaleX(0.25);
                    suitTopLeft.setScaleY(0.25);
                    //bottom left of the card( the suit)
                    HBox suitBottomRight = Heart(root);
                    suitBottomRight.setRotate(180);
                    suitBottomRight.setTranslateX(260-28);
                    suitBottomRight.setTranslateY(405+5);
                    suitBottomRight.setScaleX(0.25);
                    suitBottomRight.setScaleY(0.25);
                    //middle of the card( the suit)
                    HBox suitMiddle = Heart(root);
                    suitMiddle.setTranslateX(125-5);
                    suitMiddle.setTranslateY(210-15);
                    suitMiddle.setScaleX(0.5);
                    suitMiddle.setScaleY(0.5);
                    root.getChildren().add(suitTopLeft);
                    root.getChildren().add(suitBottomRight);
                    root.getChildren().add(suitMiddle);
                    break;
                }
            case "Diamond":
                {
                    //top left of the card (suit)
                    HBox suitTopLeft = Diamond(root);
                    suitTopLeft.setTranslateX(25+70);
                    suitTopLeft.setTranslateY(100-5);
                    //bottom left of the card( the suit)
                    HBox suitBottomRight = Diamond(root);
                    suitBottomRight.setRotate(180);
                    suitBottomRight.setTranslateX(260-27);
                    suitBottomRight.setTranslateY(405);
                    //middle of the card( the suit)
                    HBox suitMiddle = Diamond(root);
                    suitMiddle.setTranslateX(125+120);
                    suitMiddle.setTranslateY(190);
                    suitMiddle.setScaleX(0.5);
                    suitMiddle.setScaleY(0.5);
                    root.getChildren().add(suitTopLeft);
                    root.getChildren().add(suitBottomRight);
                    root.getChildren().add(suitMiddle);
                    break;
                }
            default:
                System.out.println("This is not implemented!");
                break;
        }
        
        //prints out the text of the card if the value is between 2 - 10
        
        if (2<=card.getValue()&&card.getValue()<10) {
            if(card.getSuit().equals("Spade")  || card.getSuit().equals("Club")) {
                Text text = new Text(178,120, String.valueOf(card.getValue()));
                text.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));

                Text text1 = new Text(398,520, String.valueOf(card.getValue()));
                text1.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));

                text1.setRotate(180);

                root.getChildren().add(text);
                root.getChildren().add(text1);
            }
            
            else {
                Text text = new Text(178,120, String.valueOf(card.getValue()));
                text.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));

                Text text1 = new Text(398,520, String.valueOf(card.getValue()));
                text1.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));
                text1.setRotate(180);
                text.setFill(Color.RED);
                text1.setFill(Color.RED);

                root.getChildren().add(text);
                root.getChildren().add(text1);
            }
        }
        else if (card.getValue() ==10) {
            Text text = new Text(170,120, String.valueOf(card.getValue()));
            text.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));

            Text text1 = new Text(386,520, String.valueOf(card.getValue()));
            text1.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));

            text1.setRotate(180);
            text.setFill(Color.RED);
            text1.setFill(Color.RED);

            root.getChildren().add(text);
            root.getChildren().add(text1);
        }

        else if(card.getRank() != 'N') {
            if(card.getSuit().equals("Spade") || card.getSuit().equals("Club")) {

                Text text = new Text(178,120, String.valueOf(card.getRank()));
                text.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));

                Text text1 = new Text(398,520, String.valueOf(card.getRank()));
                text1.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));
                text1.setRotate(180);

                root.getChildren().add(text);
                root.getChildren().add(text1);
            }


            else {
                Text text = new Text(178,120, String.valueOf(card.getRank()));
                text.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));

                Text text1 = new Text(398,520, String.valueOf(card.getRank()));
                text1.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 50));
                text1.setRotate(180);
                text.setFill(Color.RED);
                text1.setFill(Color.RED);
                root.getChildren().add(text);
                root.getChildren().add(text1);
                
            }
        }
        
        return root;
    }
    
    static public HBox Club(Parent parent) {

        Circle suitClubs1 = new Circle();
        suitClubs1.setTranslateX(100.0f);
        suitClubs1.setTranslateY(100.0f);
        suitClubs1.setRadius(50.0f);

        Circle suitClubs2 = new Circle();
        suitClubs2.setTranslateX(95.0f);
        suitClubs2.setTranslateY(100.0f);
        suitClubs2.setRadius(50.0f);

        Circle suitClubs3 = new Circle();
        suitClubs3.setTranslateX(-50.0f);
        suitClubs3.setTranslateY(30.0f);
        suitClubs3.setRadius(50.0f);

        Rectangle stem = new Rectangle(); 
        stem.setTranslateX(-112.0f);
        stem.setTranslateY(120.0f);
        stem.setWidth(20.0); 
        stem.setHeight(100.0);

        HBox root = new HBox(suitClubs1, suitClubs2, suitClubs3, stem);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setScaleX(0.25);
        root.setScaleY(0.25);

        HBox clubsRoot = new HBox(suitClubs1, suitClubs2, suitClubs3, stem);
        clubsRoot.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        clubsRoot.setScaleX(0.25);
        clubsRoot.setScaleY(0.25);
        clubsRoot.setTranslateX(-30);
        clubsRoot.setTranslateY(120);           
        return clubsRoot;

    }

    static public HBox Spade(Parent parent) {
        Circle suitSpade1 = new Circle();
        suitSpade1.setTranslateX(100.0f);
        suitSpade1.setTranslateY(100.0f);
        suitSpade1.setRadius(50.0f);
        suitSpade1.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        Circle suitSpade2 = new Circle();
        suitSpade2.setTranslateX(80.0f);
        suitSpade2.setTranslateY(100.0f);
        suitSpade2.setRadius(50.0f);
        suitSpade2.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        Polygon suitSpade3 = new Polygon();
        suitSpade3.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                62.0, 170.0,
                230.0, 170.0,
                146.0, 260.0,
        });
        suitSpade3.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        suitSpade3.setTranslateX(-94.0f);
        suitSpade3.setTranslateY(170.3f);    

        Rectangle stem = new Rectangle(); 
        stem.setTranslateX(-187.0f);
        stem.setTranslateY(70.0f);
        stem.setWidth(20.0); 
        stem.setHeight(100.0);

        HBox clubsRoot = new HBox(suitSpade1, suitSpade2, suitSpade3, stem);
        clubsRoot.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        clubsRoot.setScaleX(0.25);
        clubsRoot.setScaleY(0.25);
        clubsRoot.setTranslateX(-30);
        clubsRoot.setTranslateY(120);           
        return clubsRoot;
    }

    static public HBox Heart(Parent parent) {
        //drawing the suit with clubs
        Circle suitHeart1 = new Circle();
        suitHeart1.setTranslateX(100.0f);
        suitHeart1.setTranslateY(100.0f);
        suitHeart1.setRadius(50.0f);
        suitHeart1.setFill(Color.RED);

        Circle suitHeart2 = new Circle();
        suitHeart2.setTranslateX(80.0f);
        suitHeart2.setTranslateY(100.0f);
        suitHeart2.setRadius(50.0f);
        suitHeart2.setFill(Color.RED);

        Polygon suitHeart3 = new Polygon();
        suitHeart3.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                62.0, 170.0,
                230.0, 170.0,
                146.0, 260.0,
        });
        suitHeart3.setFill(Color.RED);
        suitHeart3.setTranslateX(-94.0f);
        suitHeart3.setTranslateY(175.3f);       

        HBox root = new HBox(suitHeart1, suitHeart2, suitHeart3);
        return root;
    }

    static public HBox Diamond(Parent parent) {
        Polygon suitDiamond1 = new Polygon();
        suitDiamond1.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                90.0, 170.0,
                230.0, 170.0,
                160.0, 280.0,
        });


        suitDiamond1.setFill(Color.RED);
        suitDiamond1.setTranslateX(-94.0f);
        suitDiamond1.setTranslateY(179.0f);     
        Polygon suitDiamond2 = new Polygon();
        suitDiamond2.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                90.0, 170.0,
                230.0, 170.0,
                160.0, 60.0,
        });
        suitDiamond2.setFill(Color.RED);
        suitDiamond2.setTranslateX(-234.0f);
        suitDiamond2.setTranslateY(70.0f); 

        HBox root = new HBox(suitDiamond1, suitDiamond2);
        root.setScaleX(0.25);
        root.setScaleY(0.25);

        return root;
    }
}
```

---

As stated earlier. I did not attempt to correct the alignment.

[image]